# SQL Server - Scalar function vs View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have come across some legacy code that follows this pattern:

```
select Column1, Column2, GetData(Column3, Column4)
from Table1
```

'GetData' is a scalar function that contains SQL queries.

Upon running an Extented Events session as described [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/why-scalar-functions-can-be-costly), I noted that a lot of statements were being run, over 2000 for a query that returned 190 records.

[Events run count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWp1M.png)

I surmised this can not be good as the queries in the scalar function would be run for every result set. This resulted in a client statistics report over 5 runs like this:

[Client statistics on five runs using scalar function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpHOR.png)

I generated a view that returns a dataset that matches would be returned from running the scalar function multiple times and joined it on to the original query, for example:

```
select Column1, Column2, NewView.Column3
from Table1
join NewView on NewView.Column1 = Column3 and NewView.Column2 = Column4
```

After doing so the Extended Events statement count dropped to 10, (it was over 2000 previously, see first image). The Client statistics report using the new view is:

[Client statistics on five runs using view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auTue.png)

I don't seem to have gained much in the way of speed even though the statement count has dropped considerably.

Is my way of testing this incorrect? Is the statement count (2000 vs 10), not really a consideration when looking at overall speed? Any help or advice on how to diagnose or improve is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither query is saturating a resource (cpu, disk, paging), then you might not notice any performance difference, with regard to time. However, if your machine ever becomes busy (someday), your optimization will make a difference.

IMO, your approach is a good one. If you really need to prove it, you can set up a performance test, which is a little tedious, but good experience.  In such a test, you would run each query (separately) in a loop (100x, 1000x, 10000x) while you measure time, cpu, and disk io. It will reveal which resource(s) is/are affected by the optimization.

The results might seem small, but like I said, if your system ever gets busy, each optimization will make a cumulative difference.  And it is always best to start on optimization before you encounter a problem.